# Problem with Poedit

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, translation

I have a directory structure like `theme-name/inc/lang` that I need to add the PO file inside the `lang` folder and the text to be translated is foresure inside `theme-name`. So now when I try to specifiy the `Base Path` to (.../), the Poedit shows that source code is not available.. Am I wrong to write the relative path this way? If so, How to correct this with explaination of what the Base Path is.
Here is what I have tried so far:

This worked if the lang folder was directly in the theme's folder

Base path = ../

Path= .

This didn't when the lang folder is moved to the inc folder

Base path = .../

Path = .

Answer (score 1):

`...` (3 dots) is not the same thing as `..` (two dots), but a normal directory, which, as Poedit correctly tells you, doesn't exist on your computer.

Here's how you should fix it:

1. Update your copy of Poedit to a non-ancient one (≥1.8).
2. Drag the paths that you want to extract from to the list.
3. Don't worry about base paths etc. It will do the right thing.